# Entity Framework 5 - only select entities where entity IsActive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using the Code First approach I have created a number of different entities that inherit from an interface `IConcurrent` with a property `IsActive` for example:

```
public class Currency : IConcurrent
{
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Each time I select entities I find myself always having to include a conditional clause such as this real basic example:

```
db.Currencies.Where(c => c.IsActive);
```

My question is that is it possible to some how intercept/hook into the `DbContext` so that my LINQ queries will always return `IsActive == true` for entities that inherit the IConcurrent interface, to avoid having to explicitly add `.Where(c => c.IsActive)` each time?

So far I've looked at the possible methods to override in `DbContext` which none of them seem to fit the bill. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but if the filtering is done every time wouldn't it be easier to create `ActiveCurrencies` view in the database and map it to class? :)

Comment: are you employing code first approach?

Comment: Potentially I could, although I'd still need to duplicate the work for every entity that's IConcurrent so I'd rather just include it in the code as I'm doing now. Cheers though ;-)

Comment: @daryal yes that's correct. Code First

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filtering on the [`Set<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method to get just active instances, something along the lines of:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetActive<T>() where T : class, IConcurrent
{
   return Set<T>().Where(e => e.IsActive);
}
```

This method could be included in a class that inherits the `DbContext` class, or you could make it into an extension method, like:

```
public static DbContextExtensions
{
  public static IQueryable<T> GetActive<T>(this DbContext context) 
    where T : class, IConcurrent
  {
     return context.Set<T>().Where(e => e.IsActive);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, @SWeko I like your solution, but it's not liking the constraint for the interface where T : IConcurrent. I get a Set<T> must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you need to define the `class` constraint because it is on the Set method (defined as `public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;`) in order to call it. Edited the answer to match.

Answer (score 4):

Conditional mapping is supported in Model First approach but it is not directly supported in Code first approach. You may have a workaround by creating a property in DBContext similar to the following;

```
public IQueryable<Currency> ActiveCurrencies 
{
    get 
    {
        db.Currencies.Where(c => c.IsActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daryal you got me half way there